# Find multiple results in array and echo them

Tags: php, arrays

I've got a problem and I can't seem to find any answers on how to do this.

I've got an array example:

```
$data = array(
    '8006309' => 'Pallet 1',
    '8006309' => 'Pallet 2',
    '8006309' => 'Pallet 2',
    '8006309' => 'Pallet 3',
    '8016493' => 'Pallet 4',
    '8014376' => 'Pallet 5',
    '8014375' => 'Pallet 5',
    '8014375' => 'Pallet 5',
    '8006401' => 'Pallet 6',
    '8006310' => 'Pallet 6',
    '8004263' => 'Pallet 6',
    '8001038' => 'Pallet 6',
    '8000697' => 'Pallet 6',
    '004-9866' => 'Pallet 6'
);
```

As you can see there are rows with the same data, example: 8006309. I want to show the results when I search on 8006309, example:

```
Pallet 1
Pallet 2
Pallet 2
Pallet 3
```

Currently when I'm searching for the result, I only get the last value shown.

I'm not the best programmer out there, so this question might be cringey for some of you. Though I can't quite find how to do this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where's the code that searches the array?

Comment: You can't have the same array key twice (or more) in a single array. `8006309` will only be assigned to "Pallet 3" right now (it will constantly be overwritten).

Comment: Your example is incorrect, the keys should be unique.

Comment: `$data['8006309']` itself should be an array if you want/need multiple values

Comment: Where is the input coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You assign the same array key to multiple values. "8006309" will be overwritten til it reaches the last one.

If you want to Store these Pallet Strings for every Key like 8006309 you should probably use a multidimensional array.

```
    $data = array(
                  '8006309' => array('Pallet 1', 'Pallet 2', ...),
                  '8004773' => array(...), 
                  ...);
```

SO you have only one key assigned to multiple Pallets. 
You could also have Keys in the second array like:

```
    $data = array(
                  '8006309' => array('firstOrder'=>'Pallet 1', 'secondOrder'=>'Pallet 2', ...),
                  '8004773' => array(...), 
                  ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have define your array element as another array, here is a test:

```
$data = array(
    '8006309' => array('Pallet 1','Pallet 2', 'Pallet 3'),
    '8016493' => 'Pallet 4',
    '8014376' => 'Pallet 5',
    '8014375' => 'Pallet 5',
    '8014375' => 'Pallet 5',
    '8006401' => 'Pallet 6',
    '8006310' => 'Pallet 6',
    '8004263' => 'Pallet 6',
    '8001038' => 'Pallet 6',
    '8000697' => 'Pallet 6',
    '004-9866' => 'Pallet 6'
);
```